# Number of Homomorphisms Between Finite Groups

Tags: group-theory

Assume that $G$ and $H$ are two finite groups. In general it is a very difficult question to ask about the number of homomorphisms between them, without any further assumption about their structure. However, is it true that  $ \#Hom(G,H)= \sum_{L \leqslant H} \#Epi(G,L)$, where $Epi(G,L)$ is the set of epimorphisms from $G$ to a subgroup $L\leqslant H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image of a homomorphism $ \phi : G \to H $ is necessarily a subgroup of $ H $, so any homomorphism is actually an epimorphism $ \phi: G \to L $ where $ L $ is a subgroup of $ H $. Your observation, therefore, is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i thought the same, but i haven't seen anywhere before someone to use the above and i was afraid that something isn't correct.

Comment: Also, do you know, if given an arbitrary subgroup of $H$ we can construct always a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ with image tha given subgroup?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris You can't state it even if the cardinality of $L\le H$ divides the cardinality of $G$ (which is a necessary condition for the existence of a surjective homomorphism). Consider the case where $G$ is abelian to get a bunch of counterexamples.

Comment: Yes you are right, naive question, i didn't think of it at all. There are many counterexamples in any case actually. Thank you!